# Cannot access in the second page.evaluate a variable defined in the first page.evaluate (node.js puppeteer)

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

```
await page.evaluate(() => {var a = 10; console.log(a);});
await page.evaluate(() => {console.log(a);});
```

The second one gives an error:

> Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: a is not defined

It seems that the two calls works in the 2 different browser's contexts?

Also I cannot access this variable in the browser's console, however the browser's logs are displaying:

[image: also I cannot access this variable in the browser's console, however the browser's logs are displaying]

Comment: Declare the `a` variable outside the callback of `evaluate` via `let a` then inside the callback use `a = 10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var` variables are function-scoped, so in your case `a` is defined only inside the first function. You can make it global:

```js
  await page.evaluate(() => { window.a = 10; console.log(a); });
  await page.evaluate(() => { console.log(a); });
```

or save and transfer from context to context:

```js
  const a = await page.evaluate(() => { var a = 10; console.log(a); return a; });
  await page.evaluate((a) => { console.log(a); }, a);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The first solution works brilliantly!